# How can I get the contents of the currently active keyboard layout in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to add keybinding functionality to my bearlibterminal project. Currently, using

```
from bearlibterminal import terminal
terminal.open()
terminal.refresh()
terminal.read()
print(chr(terminal.state(terminal.TK_WCHAR)))
```

I can get the proper unicode symbol for the current keyboard layout (for example, the same key gives me [ for the US layout and ü for the German layout).

What I want is to be able to use "shift-ü" to match "Ü", or "shift-[" in the US layout to match "{", or "alt-q" in the German layout to match "@".

I believe to do this I need to be able to both determine the currently active keyboard layout (for which I was able to find a bit) and the contents of the layout (for which I found nothing). Is this possible?